# For Loop | Python

Tags: python

I am using Python first time for web scraping and while doing a code, I got stuck into a for loop.

As we can see, both b and a returns a list. I am using for loop to iterate over the list values of both b and a, and print it in like a sequence :

Desired Output

```
first value of b, first value of a, second value of b, second value of a....
```

Here is the code :

```
b = soup.find("module", {"type":"Featured Link List Advanced"}).find_all("span")

a = soup.find("module", {"type":"Featured Link List Advanced"}).find("ul").find_all("a")\

for i in b:
   print (i.string)
   for j in a:
      print (j.get("href"))
      break
```

But the output I am getting is :

```
First value of b, First value of a, second value of b, first value of a, third value of, first value of a,
```

Can some help me in getting the desired output ? I know I am missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over 2 sequences in parallel:

```
for (i,j) in zip(b,a):
   print (i.string)
   print (j.get("href"))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out . Much appreciated.